# Can HTTP headers be localized?

Tags: http, localization

The HTTP Accept header can specify priority using the `q` specifier, such as

```
application/xml;q=0.8
```

I had a look in the RFC but could see any mention of whether the `q` specifier is subject to localization or not. For instance, could a European browser send the figure as `q=0,8` instead if the `Accept-Language` was set accordingly?

If not, there must be some documentation somewhere that specifies that HTTP uses the period notation and is culture invariant in its headers I guess?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Section 3.9](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec3.html#sec3.9) of [RFC-2616](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616.html) (the HTTP/1.1 spec) defines a Quality Value (the value assigned to 'q' in your example) as:

```
qvalue         = ( "0" [ "." 0*3DIGIT ] )
               | ( "1" [ "." 0*3("0") ] )
```

so all HTTP applications must use a decimal point, not a comma or anything else, regardless of where in the world they reside.

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I was looking for and failed to find :)

Answer (score 1):

A technical protocol is always culture-independent - it's technical, not American or anything. Of course you can not localize anything in a HTTP header. You can also not localize the header fields by translating them to the language that it is used in the country the browser is run or written in.

Comment: Technical protocols are usually “culture-independent,” which means in practice that they are based on US English, to the extent that they use expressions resembling a human language. There is however no guarantee that every protocol always follows this principle. Ultimately, such things are defined in each protocol specification.

Comment: This is of course correct, but I think if you are asking these questions about the HTTP protocol, you are following the wrong line of thought ;).